# Keep Page Data on Refresh With $_POST

Tags: php, http-post

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <h1>Table Generator</h1>
</head>
<body>

<center><a href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">Refresh</a></center>

<?php
    $rows = (isset($_POST['rows']) ? $_POST['rows'] : null);
    $cols = (isset($_POST['cols']) ? $_POST['cols'] : null);
    $highlight = (isset($_POST['highlight']) ? $_POST['highlight'] : null);

    if ($rows == "")
    {
        $rows = 10;
    }

    if ($cols == "")
    {
        $cols = 10;
    }

    if ($highlight == "")
    {
        $highlight = 5;
    }
?>
    <form method="post">
        ROWS <input type="text" name="rows" value = "<?php echo $rows;?>" /> 
        COLUMNS <input type="text" name="cols" value = "<?php echo $cols;?>" />
        HIGHLIGHT <input type = "text" name = "highlight" value = "<?php echo $highlight;?>" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Generate">
    </form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['rows']))
{

    $randnumber = rand(0,100);

    $rows = $_POST['rows'];
    $cols = $_POST['cols'];
    $highlight = $_POST['highlight'];

    echo '<table border="1" align = "center">';

    if (is_numeric($rows) and is_numeric($cols) and is_numeric($highlight))
    {
        if ($randnumber % 2 == 0)
        {
            echo '<center>The first number is <div class = "red">even</div></center>';
        }

        else
        {
            echo '<center>The first number is <div class = "green">odd</div></center>';
        }

        for($row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++)
        {
            echo '<tr style = "background-color:green">';

            for($col = 1; $col <= $cols; $col++)
            {
                if ($randnumber % $highlight == 0)
                {
                    echo '<td style = "background-color: red">';
                    echo $randnumber;
                    $randnumber++;
                    echo '</td>';
                }

                else
                {
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo $randnumber;
                    $randnumber++;
                    echo '</td>';
                }
            }

            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';

    }

    else
    {
        echo "<center>Rows / Columns / Highlight must ALL be INTEGER values. Re-enter correct value(s).</center>";
    }

    echo '<pre><center>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</center></pre>';
}
?>

<style type ="text/css">
h1 {
    color: grey;
    text-align:center;
}

form {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}

.green {
    color: green;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

So. I have this PHP code to generate a table based off the user's input and I recently ran into a problem I cant figure out how to fix.

It was working perfectly fine but now whenever I use the Refresh link it resets the entire page to default (i.e. default textbox values instead of keeping the current ones, removing the table).

So, I have 2 questions. How would I keep the data on refresh (with $_POST being used) and how to display the table with the default values when the page first loads.

Comment: After POST, when you refresh it, the browser asks if you want to resend data. If you click Resend, it'll refresh with the data sent by the first POST.

Comment: Cookies or Sessions? Client side alternatives could be local storage. Ofcourse you w"on'T be using `$-_POST`. Apologies about the random mistakes in the sentences, it seems my keyboard is giving up on me.

Comment: Yes, when I refresh the page it works. HOWEVER. I want to refresh the page using the refresh button. Clicking the refresh button just resets it as if the page loaded for the first time. EDIT - haven't learned to use cookies or sessions. I have code as is and it worked before

Comment: @James what is `refresh link` mean in the question? So after validating if any error occury you want all the values to be present and error displayed??

Comment: I have a link in the HTML page with the Text refresh.

<center><a href = "<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">Refresh</a></center> (near the top of the code).

When I clicked that, it would display a newly generated table of different  numbers and keeps text box values. Now it just resets everything.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies everybody! Got it working now!

Comment: @James please revert your last edit. You removed the original problem from your question, it now may confuse people who can't see how chosen answer is relevant to the question.

Comment: The convention says you should use GET in this case. POST usually means there are side-effects, and that's why browsers don't resend the form data.

Comment: Roeland, I used GET before but re-read the assignment and he said to use POST so I tried to make it work using that.

@DeDee Mmm.. Didn't think of that. Was just excited it was fixed :)

PaulCrovella Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:location.reload()">Refresh</a>
```

Clicking it will trigger browser's reload mechanism and you'll be asked to resubmit the form action, it will allow you to keep POST data.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Don't know if my teacher wants the $_SERVER['post']; specifically but this worked!

Didn't have to switch to $_GET (It worked with $_GET). Thanks!

Also, it doesn't prompt to resend data as you said, so I don't know but it works anyways.

Comment: It does in Firefox, depends on the browser, glad it works for you :)

Comment: @James If this isn't what your teacher wants. You could use `seralize` and sessions to do this task also

Comment: Meant to say $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] instead of ['POST'].

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-create the post if you want to keep the parameters. Can be done pretty eaily by looping thru the array.

```
<form method='POST' id='refresh' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'>
<?php foreach($_POST as $k=>$v): ?>
<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $k; ?>' value='<?php echo $v; ?>' />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<a href='#' onclick='document.getElementById("refresh").submit(); return false;'>refresh</a>
</form>
```

Note: This is a little longer than the other answer, but will not prompt to resend post data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It worked too but that one was shorter and still didn't prompt for w/e reason. Thanks for quick reply!